# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION using rocketeer

Tags: html, string, parsing, function, syntax

```
uksort($actions, function($a, $b){
            if(strlen($a) == strlen($b)) {
            return 0;
        }
        if(strlen($a) > strlen($b)) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 1;
```

Whats wrong here??

Comment: please include your code in the correct bbcode-tag ...

Comment: you cannot bass the function directly like in javascript (PHP verion less then 5.3)! You have to pass the name of the function as string ... See manual of http://php.net/uksort

Comment: @tuxtimo Anonymous functions?

Comment: He does not have a PHP version greater or equal than 5.3 ...

Answer (score 0):

You are running a version of PHP older than 5.3, in which anonymous functions did not exist.

Comment: soo i need a newer version of PHP?

Comment: That, or don't use anonymous functions.

Comment: i did it just keeps moving down the lines, i have to change every single one?

Answer (score 0):

```
function cmp($a, $b){
    if(strlen($a) == strlen($b)) {
        return 0;
    }
    if(strlen($a) > strlen($b)) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 1;
 }

 uksort( $actions, "cmp" );
```

You cannot use closures because your version must be newer or equal `5.3`... 
That's the reason why you have to pass the function name as a string ;)

Comment: so i changed two sections of the original code but at the end i get. Fatal error: Cannot redeclare cmp() (previously declared in /home/linden/public_html/ian/system/core/Router.php:378)